# Add a prefix to a CSS file

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code which allows me to swap prefixes of images which works great thanks to maniator!

```
    $(function() {
    $('img.swap').each(function(){     
    $(this).data('current_image', this.src);     
}) 
$('a').click(function(){          
        var prefix = $(this).attr("class");       
         $('img.swap').each(       
         function() {           
            if($(this).data('prefix') != prefix){            
            this.src = $(this).data('current_image').replace('.gif', (prefix)+'.gif');
            $(this).data('prefix', prefix)          
    }         
     else {            
     this.src = $(this).data('current_image');           
      $(this).data('prefix', '')          
      }       
       });  
      }); 
 });
```

My question is am I able to add the same prefix which is being added to the image to a certain CSS file, in this instance it will be color.css so could I make it color_bw.css?

Many Thanks

Comment: yes :) I have had a few attempts but I am just starting out with jQuery so it really isnt my strong point at the momement

Answer (score 0):

yes the link tag that links the css is the same as anyother element

set the href like this

```
<link id="css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.css" type="text/css" />

var css = $("#css").attr("href");
var href = css.replace(".css",css+prefix);
$("#css").attr("href",href);
```